# Limit of the binomial coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, binomial-coefficients

Function $v_n$ takes the values of the binomial coefficients as inputs:
$v_1=m,\; v_2=\frac{m(m-1)}{1\cdot2},\; ..., v_n=\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)...(m-n+1)}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot...\cdot n},..., \;$ where $m$ is a positive integer.

Find$$\lim_{n\to\infty} v_n$$

source: Berman. G.N. A Problem Book in Mathematical Analysis, Moscow, 1967.

Comment: Are you sure that's the question? We have $v_k = 0 $ for $k > m$? Do you want $+$ signs instead?

Comment: If $m$ is a positive integer, then the numerator becomes $0$ at some point on. You'll have $(m-m)$ as a factor for large enough $n$'s.

Comment: No, it says this.

Comment: That is what was confusing me beause I know n can't be greater than m.

Comment: Well, it can be greater. It's just that ${m\choose n}=0$ for $n>m$ and $m$ a positive integer. So the limit, as stated, is just $0$.

Comment: But, the value of the binomial coefficient, as I learned, can be at least 1, and in my workbook, it says $n\geq m\geq 0$, is that false? If it is, I'll go through everything at least twice again. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Indeed, it is stated exactly this way in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to notice that the terms of the sequence become $0$ from some point on. When $n>m$, you have
$$v_n=\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)\cdots(m-m)\cdots(m-n+1)}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots n}=0$$
Using binomial coefficients, this is saying that ${m\choose n}=0$ for $n>m$.
Since the sequence consists of just zeros eventually, you have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}v_n=0 $$